# Java swing Key Binding for multiple JPanels

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings

i working on a little game (rpg) in java and i need to move my character with UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT in different panel who represent each level of my game.

I use KeyListener first and this is working fine for the first panel, but not with the other.

I try to make this work with a method who make the movement with panelNumber in argument : (this is working only for the first panel) :

```
    private void panelSalle2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
      int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
      deplacementJoueurSalle(keyCode, 2);
    }  

private void characterMove(int keyCode, int panelNumber){
    JLabel panelCharacterSprite= new JLabel();

    switch(panelNumber){
        case 1:
            panelCharacterSprite= characterPanel1;
            break;
        case 2:
            panelCharacterSprite= characterPanel2;
            break;
        case 3:
            panelCharacterSprite= imagePersoSalle3;
            break;
        default:
            imagePerso = null;
            break;
    }
    int x = panelCharacterSprite.getX();
    int y = panelCharacterSprite.getY();

    switch( keyCode ) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        if(y-10 >= -3){
            panelCharacterSprite.setLocation(x, y-10);
        }
        break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        if(y+10 <= 417){
            panelCharacterSprite.setLocation(x, y+10);
        }
        break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        if(x-10 >= -1){
            panelCharacterSprite.setLocation(x-10, y);
        }
        break;
        case panelCharacterSprite.VK_RIGHT :
        if(x+10 <= 671){
            panelCharacterSprite.setLocation(x+10, y);
        }
```

I see on stackoverflow that i have to use key binding for make this but i don't really understand how its work.. do it have a chance that i can make work with keylistener ?

Thx

Comment: See [getInputMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap-int-) and [getActionMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getActionMap--).

Comment: how does it work ? i need to do a "WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW" ?

Comment: `I see on stackoverflow that i have to use key binding` yes, because Key Bindings is the better solution. `do it have a chance that i can make work with keylistener ?` no, because only one component can have focus. That is why Key Bindings is always suggested, it is not limited by this restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/).

The `KeyboardAnimation.java` example shows how you can use Key Bindings on two different components and have both components do animation at the same time while a key is pressed.